# Error in React while using Router Expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to redirect to another page. I am new to React. I used `Router` for moving to other page. However i get the following error:

Here is my code:

```js
import Head from 'next/head';
import { Box, Container, Grid, Pagination } from '@mui/material';
import { products } from '../__mocks__/products';
import { ProductListToolbar } from '../components/product/product-list-toolbar';
import { ProductCard } from '../components/product/product-card';
import { DashboardLayout } from '../components/dashboard-layout';
import { CustomerListResults } from '../components/trip/trip-list-results';
import { customers } from '../__mocks__/customers';
import { trips } from '../__mocks__/trips';
import { TripListResults } from '../components/customer/customer-list-results';
import React, { BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Redirect, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import {
    Avatar,
    Card,
    Checkbox,
    Table,
    TableBody,
    TableCell,
    TableHead,
    TablePagination,
    TableRow,
    Typography,
    Button
} from '@mui/material';
import NextLink from 'next/link';

const TripRequests = () => {

    const [acceptState, setAcceptState] = useState(true);
    const accept = () => setAcceptState(false);

    return (
        <>
        <Router>
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={DashboardLayout } />
            <Head>
                <title>
                    Trip Requests
                </title>
            </Head>
            <Box
                component="main"
                sx={{
                    flexGrow: 1,
                    py: 8
                }}
            >
                <Container maxWidth={false}>
                    <Box sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
                        {/* <CustomerListResults customers={trips} /> */}
                        <h2>Trip Requests (1)</h2>
                    </Box>
                    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 1050, mt: 3 }}>
                        <Table>
                            <TableHead>
                                <TableRow>
                                    <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                                        {/* <Checkbox
                    // checked={selectedCustomerIds.length === customers.length}
                    color="primary"
                    // indeterminate={
                    //   selectedCustomerIds.length > 0
                    //   && selectedCustomerIds.length < customers.length
                    // }
                    // onChange={handleSelectAll}
                  /> */}
                                    </TableCell>
                                    {/* <TableCell>
                  Trip Id
                </TableCell> */}
                                    <TableCell>
                                        Customer
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>
                                        Departure
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>
                                        Destination
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>
                                        Truck / Driver
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>
                                        Action
                                    </TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableHead>
                            <TableBody>

                                <TableRow

                                    hover
                                //   key={customer.id}
                                //   selected={selectedCustomerIds.indexOf(customer.id) !== -1}
                                >
                                    <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                                        {/* <Checkbox
                      checked={selectedCustomerIds.indexOf(customer.id) !== -1}
                      onChange={(event) => handleSelectOne(event, customer.id)}
                      value="true"
                    /> */}
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>
                                        Rohan Joshi
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>
                                        <Box
                                            sx={{
                                                alignItems: 'center',
                                                display: 'flex'
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            {/* <Avatar
                        src={customer.avatarUrl}
                        sx={{ mr: 2 }}
                      >
                        {getInitials(customer.name)}
                      </Avatar> */}
                                            <Typography
                                                color="textPrimary"
                                                variant="body1"
                                            >
                                                A-50, Sec 67, Noida
                                            </Typography>
                                        </Box>
                                    </TableCell>

                                    <TableCell>
                                        HUDA City Center
                                    </TableCell>

                                    <TableCell>
                                        Truck #123 / Ravi Shukla
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>
                                        {acceptState ? (
                                            <><Button onClick={accept}>Accept</Button><Button>Decline</Button></>
                                        ) : <p>Pending Payment</p>}

                                    </TableCell>

                                    {/* <TableCell>
                    {format(customer.createdAt, 'dd/MM/yyyy')}
                  </TableCell> */}
                                </TableRow>

                            </TableBody>
                        </Table>
                    </Box>

                </Container>
            </Box>
            {/* <Redirect to="/" /> */}

            </Switch>
        </Router>
        </>
      
    );
};

TripRequests.getLayout = (page) => (
    <DashboardLayout>
        {page}
    </DashboardLayout>
);

export default TripRequests;
```

Comment: You need to import `BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route` from `react-router-dom` but you imported from `react`.

Answer (score 0):

Import Router objects from react-router-dom instead of react

import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Switch,
Route,
Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

Comment: I get this error now: `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the latest react-router-dom, the route should be configured like below. Initially you need to import all the dependencies from react-router-dom. Also, all the routes should be wrapped inside `<Routes></Routes>`.

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './Components/Home'
import Functioncontext from './Components/Functioncontext'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/context" element={<Functioncontext />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The above code works on `"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"`. Before react-router-dom version 6. It has to be configured in the different way.

Comment: I get this error now: `ReferenceError: document is not defined`

Comment: Did you try implementing the above code ???

Comment: I did and told you the result of it.

Comment: You are using next js right ???

Comment: I am using React along with Material UI, dont have an idea if my project includes Next Js too.

Comment: Okay... Since there is `NextLink`. There must be next js in your project. In that case next js makes server side rendering. In that case, There will be no browser involved during the server side rendering. So If you have provided any `window` or `document` in your project. You will be getting this error. Please check the other files too whether you have used `window` or `document` in your project.

Comment: Also If you really don't want next js. Do remove it. You can check whether next js is installed or not in the package.json file in your project